# The onchange event not working. Select dropdown coming from the controller

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3, onchange

I have a select dropdown which comes from the controller using JSON and displaying on the view page.

Now my on change event is not working. If I added a select drop down direct on view then it's working but which is come from the controller that is not working.

**Controller**

```
$code.= '<!--more HTML code here-->

 I have more html code here

 <select name="yearDropdown"  class="form-control dropdownDuration">
 <option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
 <option value="12m" <?php if($product['options']['duration'] == "12m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >1 Year</option>
 <option value="6m" <?php if($product['options']['duration'] == "6m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6 months</option>
 </select>

I have more html code here

    <!--more HTML code here-->
    ';
```

**on change script**

```
$('.dropdownDuration').change(function () {
alert('hello');
});
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url:baseUrl+"/Member_controller/Section",
       // context: document.body,
       dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
           //alert("done");
          //alert(data);

          $('#ProcessModel').html(data);
        }});
```

});

**view**

```
<div id="ProcessModel"></div>
```

Comment: @Rory, I think you have to check again my question.

Comment: No, it's a duplicate. If you read that question you will understand why this does not work. Your fix is to use `$(document).on('change', '.dropdownDuration', function() { ... ` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, oh! yes, your last comment is working for me. Thanks for the help. I was confused in the duplicate link.

Answer (score 1):

Because **.ajax()** is asynchronous you need to delegate the change event because the select element (i.e.: dropdownDuration)  does not exist yet:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = '<!--more HTML code here-->' +
            '<select name="yearDropdown"  class="form-control dropdownDuration">' +
            '<option selected disabled >Select duration</option>' +
            '<option value="12m">1 Year</option>' +
            '<option value="6m">6 months</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '<!--more HTML code here-->';
    $('#ProcessModel').html(data);
})

$('#ProcessModel').on('change', '.dropdownDuration', function () {
    console.log('hello: ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="ProcessModel"></div>
<button>Simulate ajax</button>
```

Comment: You added the select code in the script. but I am getting from the controller and I have some logic part in the above select dropdown.

Comment: @user9437856 No, I added the select code inside the button click. If you don't click the button no select code is added to the ProcessModel..... It's a way to simulate the arror condition